# Avoiding writing DTO with unnecessary fields

Tags: json, jackson

I am making a call to third party REST Web Service. It returns me huge JSON string with lots of fields but I only need few of them. I am using `jackson` `ObjectMapper` like this :

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
myDetailDto =  mapper.readValue(inputLine, new TypeReference<MyDetailDto>(){});
```

Is there a way I don't have to include all fields in `MyDetailDto`?

Comment: Are you asking for a way to make jackson ObjectMapper automagically return only the fields you want without writing your own wrapper code?

Comment: No ... I am asking if there is any other 'way of coding' where I don't have to write 100s of fields that is being never used and put @JsonIgnoreProperties for most.

Comment: If that's all you want, then the answer is a resounding, 'yes! Dozens of ways'. It all depends on how much code you want to write and what restrictions you have on this new code are. For example, you could remove jackson and do everything yourself. Without some clear restrictions about what the new code needs todo - or an example of the new code you tried, this may get votes to close for being too broad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make your `MyDetailDto` to have only the fields that you are interested and in the `class` level, add the `@annotation` to ignore unknown properties.

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class MyDetailDto {  }
```